# ZFC Axioms in Strutures

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms

I'm really struggeling with a logic task and I need a hint how to solve these kind of Problems.

Q: Which of the ZFC Axioms are valid on the Structures:
(1) ($Z$,<)
(2) (R,<)

I really dont see how any of the ZFC Axioms are not valid because R, Z are sets...

Comment: Do you know exactly what it means for an axiom to be valid in a structure?  If not, review the definition until you do!

Comment: In our lecture a Structure S satisfies a sentence/axiom if S is a Model of the sentence/axiom.

Comment: For each ZF axiom, rewrite it with epsilon symbol (set membership) replaced with < (less than) and decide if the resulting sentence is true in the (1) integers and (2) reals.

Answer (score 3):

The ZFC axioms do not describe sets - rather, they (purport to) describe *how the universe of sets behaves with respect to "$\in$".* That is, "model of ZFC" doesn't mean "thing which is a set" but "*structure* which looks like the universe of *all* sets."

To see how this plays out, let's take a couple of the more concrete ZFC axioms and look at how they behave in general structures in the appropriate language (= one binary relation $E$):

- **Pairing**: $\forall x,y\exists z\forall u(uEz\leftrightarrow (u=x\vee u=y))$. When we look at the structure $(\mathbb{R};<)$, this statement is clearly *false*: no real number is greater than only two real numbers!
- **Extensionality**: $\forall x,y(\forall z(zEx\leftrightarrow zEy)\leftrightarrow x=y)$. This statement is clearly *true* in $(\mathbb{R};<)$, since any two real numbers which are greater than exactly the same things are equal.

Now you need to continue through the remaining axioms ...